# Centering SVG text on IE11 with text-anchor: middle and alignment-baseline: middle / central

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

I need to perfectly center a text element in an SVG using IE11.

Desired result (all Evergreen browsers):
[image]

IE11 result:
[image]

// SVG CODE:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100% height="100%" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
    <circle fill="dodgerblue" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="65"></circle>
    <text text-anchor="middle"
        alignment-baseline="central"
        font-size="75"
        font-family="Arial"
        x="50%" y="50%">1</text>
  </svg>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/craig-o-curtis/pen/WMXqwe)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IE doesn't support `alignment-baseline`.  The best cross-browser way to achieve what you want is to use the `dy` attribute with a fractional `em` value.

A value of around `dy="0.35"` works for Arial.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100% height="100%" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
  <circle fill="dodgerblue" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="65"></circle>
  <text text-anchor="middle"
        font-size="75"
        font-family="Arial"
        x="50%" y="50%" dy="0.35em">1</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Probably a silly question... but, could you elaborate the reason why is 0.35em and not 0.5em ? I mean, if 1em = height of font, offseting it by 0.5em should do the trick (but it's not)...

Comment: It's because the vertical centre of a character glyph doesn't usually correspond to the vertical centre of an em height.  Things like the space reserved for descenders tend to push glyphs upward in the em box. [See this diagram from the Microsoft site, for example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/images/op-example15.gif)

Comment: You may need to tweak the value depending on your needs. But once you find a `em` amount that looks right for a font, it should work for any size of that font.

Answer (score 0):

Also agreed with @Paul LeBeau. In addition, I used this tool https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor to remove whitespace. The following worked well for me:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 130 130" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle fill="dodgerblue" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="65"/><text font-family="Arial" font-size="75" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%" dy="0.36em">1</text></svg>
```

I could handle the removing whitespace task with Javascript:

```
let svg = `
    <svg viewBox="0 0 130 130" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle fill="dodgerblue" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="65"/>
        <text font-family="Arial" font-size="75" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%" dy="0.36em">1</text>
    </svg>
`;

// Note: Hack for IE11
// Optimize HTML by removing whitespace
// Ref: https://jaketrent.com/post/remove-whitespace-html-javascript/
svg = svg.replace(/\n/g, '') // remove newline/carriage return
    .replace(/[\t ]+\</g, '<') // remove whitespace (space and tabs) before tags
    .replace(/\>[\t ]+\</g, '><') // remove whitespace between tags
    .replace(/\>[\t ]+$/g, '>'); // remove whitespace after tags
```